# How to export the percentage value in amchart V3 export functionality

Tags: javascript, export-to-excel, export-to-csv, amcharts

I'm drawing a pie chart using AmCharts V3 and am using the export plugin to export the data as a file. I'm displaying a percentage contibution of the sale in different countries and would like to also display this percentage when I export my data to a CSV or XLSX file, but I'm not able to do so.

Here is my code

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdivtaxes", {
  type: "pie",
  startDuration: 0,
  theme: "light",
  addClassNames: true,
  labelText: "[[percents]]",
  innerRadius: "30%",
  labelFunction: function(value, valueText, valueAxis) {
    valueText = parseFloat(valueText);
    var percentageText = valueText
      .toFixed(1)
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,");
    return percentageText + "%";
  },

  defs: {
    filter: [
      {
        id: "shadow",
        width: "200%",
        height: "200%",
        feOffset: {
          result: "offOut",
          in: "SourceAlpha",
          dx: 0,
          dy: 0
        },
        feGaussianBlur: {
          result: "blurOut",
          in: "offOut",
          stdDeviation: 5
        },
        feBlend: {
          in: "SourceGraphic",
          in2: "blurOut",
          mode: "normal"
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  dataProvider: [
    {
      countryName: "India",
      country: "sale in india:",
      litres: "800.00"
    },
    {
      countryName: "africa",
      country: "sale in africa:",
      litres: "800.00"
    },
    {
      countryName: "UK",
      country: "sale in UK:",
      litres: "800.00"
    },
    {
      countryName: "US",
      country: "sale in US:",
      litres: "800.00"
    }
  ],
  valueField: "litres",
  titleField: "country",
  balloon: {
    fixedPosition: false,
    color: "#ffffff",
    fillAlpha: 0.9,
    fillColor: "#00000"
  },
  export: {
    enabled: true,
    divId: "exportLevy",
    columnNames: {
      litres: "TotalSale",
      countryName: "Name"
    },
    menu: [
      {
        class: "export-main",
        label: "Export",
        menu: [
          {
            format: "XLSX"
          },
          {
            format: "CSV"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],

    exportFields: ["countryName", "litres", "percents"]
  }
});
```

Comment: I was wondering how this can work with amcharts v4, and I created a new question for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858263/how-to-export-the-percentage-value-in-amcharts-v4-export-functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about this - both of which involve using the `processData` callback offered by the export plugin.

1) Use `processData` to add a percent property in your data and manually trigger a download with `toCSV` or `toXLSX`. Note that you will need to throw an exception to prevent the plugin from triggering the download multiple times:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  export: {
    // ...
    processData: function(data, cfg) {
      //only for CSV and XLSX export. Wrap in an ignore call to prevent infinite loop
      if ((cfg.format === "CSV" || cfg.format === "XLSX") && !cfg.ignoreThatRequest) {
        var sum = data.reduce(function(accumulator, currentDataValue) {
          return accumulator + parseFloat(currentDataValue.TotalSale);
        }, 0);

        data.forEach(function(currentDataValue) {
          currentDataValue.percents =
            (parseFloat(currentDataValue.TotalSale) / sum * 100).toFixed(1) + "%";
        });
        //will map to this.toCSV or this.toXLSX
        this["to" + cfg.format]({
            data: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)),
            ignoreThatRequest: true, //set ignore flag as processData will execute again when this is called
            exportFields: ["Name", "TotalSale", "percents"]
          },
          function(output) {
            this.download(output, cfg.mimeType, cfg.fileName + "." + cfg.extension);
          }
        );
        throw "Invoked – Use custom handler (stop multiple download)"; //throw an exception to stop the multi-download attempt
      }

      return data;
    }
  }
});
```

[Demo of method #1](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/d2721c41016a4638b9a4b3d58e31fbd7?editors=0010)

2) Alternatively, add a dummy `percents` property in your dataProvider with its value set to null and use `processData` to fill it in before exporting the chart. This is simpler and doesn't require an exception workaround to prevent multiple downloads:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("...", {
  // ...
  export: {
  // ...
    processData: function(data, cfg) {
        var sum = data.reduce(function(accumulator, currentDataValue) {
          return accumulator + parseFloat(currentDataValue.TotalSale);
        }, 0);

        data.forEach(function(currentDataValue) {
          currentDataValue.percents =
            (parseFloat(currentDataValue.TotalSale) / sum * 100).toFixed(1) + "%";
        }); 
      return data;
    }
  }
});
```

[Demo of method #2](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/5a5b9d6947888c0e5b2901a7390e0381?editors=0010)