# How to export the percentage value in amcharts V4 export functionality

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

My question is basically the same as [How to export the percentage value in amchart V3 export functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44151820), but using amcharts v4 instead of v3: I want to export the percentage values calculated by amcharts using the `chart.exporting` functionality.

This is what I have so far. I calculate the percentages and show them in the graph:

```
const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.categoryX = 'hoursCount';
series.dataFields.valueY = 'clientsCount';
series.name = 'Visits';
series.calculatePercent = true;
series.dataFields.valueYShow = 'percent';
```

Then, I'm configuring the export:

```
chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
chart.exporting.dataFields = {
      hoursCount: 'Name of bins',
      clientsCount: 'Number of clients',
};
```

However, how can I add the pct calculated by amcharts v4 to the export?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@otmezger has already set it up.
`series.calculatePercent = true;`
This means that percentages will be computed twice.

```
chart.exporting.adapter.add("data", function(data) {
    var sum = data.data.reduce(function(accumulator, currentDataValue) {
        return accumulator + parseFloat(currentDataValue.clientsCount);
    }, 0);
    data.data.forEach(function(currentDataValue) {
        currentDataValue.percents =
            (parseFloat(currentDataValue.clientsCount) / sum * 100).toFixed(1) + "%";
    });
    return data;
});
```

The problem has been resolved by retrieving the data from chart.series.

```
chart.exporting.adapter.add("data", function(data, target) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.data.length; i++) {
        var v0 = chart.series._values[0];
        data.data[i].percent = Math.round((v0.dataItems.values[i].values.value.percent || 0) * 10) / 10;
    }
    return data;
});
```

In the new version, it does not calculate percentages twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.exporting.adapter.add("data", function(data) {
    var sum = data.data.reduce(function(accumulator, currentDataValue) {
        return accumulator + parseFloat(currentDataValue.clientsCount);
    }, 0);
    data.data.forEach(function(currentDataValue) {
        currentDataValue.percents =
            (parseFloat(currentDataValue.clientsCount) / sum * 100).toFixed(1) + "%";
    });
    return data;
});
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68990362/16787076), please.